# HTC desire x issues after update to Android 4.1 Sense 4+

Tags: performance, htc-desire-x

Ever since I installed the update to 4.1 I've been having major issues with my desire x.

- The keyboard disappears frequently while typing, sometimes I can't get it back without closing the app and restarting.
- When I exit a lot of apps, but most notably any of the browsers (I use Firefox and Chrome but have also tried the standard browser) the home screen shows the loading symbol for several seconds and I have to wait before I can do anything.
- Lots of apps close without warning.

This phone has gone from a great easy to use, relatively fast and reliable phone into something I can barely use for typing on. I did a factory reset a month ago which helped for a short time but now the problem is worse than ever. Continuously doing a factory reset is not a solution!

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this? I should note I am using SwiftKey but it makes no difference if I use the standard keyboard.